# How to make VS 2013 build process handle the app.config file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, compilation, app-config

I have a simple Windows console application with an app.config file. For some reason, the build process does not rename this file (to match the name of the executable). If I change the project settings to enable the VSHOST process, then the VSHOST.EXE.CONFIG version gets built, but I cannot figure out how to make Visual Studio generate the standard .config file matching the name of the executable. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that you are looking in the right build folder .. `Debug || Release` folder.. check the release folder maybe it's getting built there.

Comment: I'm sure. :-) As I said, I can see the VSHOST config files there (when configured to use VSHOST.EXE.CONFIG), but not EXE.CONFIG. Actually, when I turn the VSHOST option off and on, the EXE.CONFIG file gets generated, but it disappears after I do  rebuild.